# Bubble Sort in Forth (for strings)

Tags: beginner, algorithm, sorting, forth

I wrote the following Forth code for sorting a string with the Bubble Sort method.

It looks nice to my eyes, but I'd like your experienced opinion and any comments about the code you might have.

1. In the `compare-and-swap-next` word, is using the return stack to save base address of string ok?
2. the `bubblesort` word uses `2 pick` which is not so bad? A previous version had `5 pick` (!), anyway ... is `2 pick` *fine: don't overthink about that* or maybe try some more refactoring?
3. How would I go about adding a check for any swaps in each round and terminate the sort early? A variable? A stack cell (on TOS)? Rethink all of the implementation?

```
: compare-and-swap-next ( string i -- )
   2dup + dup >r c@ rot rot 1 + + c@ 2dup >
   if     r@ c! r> 1 + c!
   else   r> drop 2drop
   then ;

: bubblesort ( string len -- string len )
   dup 1 -
   begin  dup 0>
   while  dup 0
          do   2 pick i compare-and-swap-next
          loop
          1 -
   repeat
   drop ;

\ s" abracadabra" bubblesort \ cr type
\ s" The quick brown fox" bubblesort \ cr type
\ s" a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." bubblesort \ cr type
```

Code available [on github](https://github.com/pm62eg/LearningForth/blob/900c773f8303a939b5172f0b35e9ba1a6cb08c37/sorts.fs)

Nitpicks welcome! Pedantism welcome!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your immediate concerns,

1. Using the return stack for storing your temporaries is a perfectly valid technique.
2. `pick` is always frown upon (as well as `tuck`, `roll`, and friends). It *seems* that the `len` parameter to `bubblesort` does not participate in computation - except the very beginning - and mostly just stays in the way. Consider

   ```
    : bubblesort
        dup >r 1-
        ....
   ```

and use `over` instead of `2 pick` (don't forget to `r>` the length at the end).

---

I prefer a slightly different formatting of conditional. Consider

```
2dup > if     
    r@ c! r> 1 + c!  else   
    r> drop 2drop then ;
```

Same for the loops. Consider

```
: bubblesort ( string len -- string len )
    dup 1 - begin 
    dup 0> while
        dup 0 do                                      
            2 pick i compare-and-swap-next               
        loop
        1 -                                     
    repeat
drop ;
```

Keeping control words together with their respective conditions/actions looks more Forthy for me.

---

`r> drop` is also known as `rdrop`.

`rot rot` is also known as `-rot`.